# Is there some way to delete a particular Tmux session name?

Tags: tmux

I have, at some point in time, created a tmux session called `cpp`. At some other point in time this session was deleted: If I try to `^prefix ls` I do not see the session listed. But now I want to create a new session called `cpp` and tmux is adding a numeric suffix when I do: `tmux new -t cpp`. For example, it returns `cpp-2` as the session name when I list sessions. Is there some way to delete all past session names that are called `cpp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: Next time use `-s` instead of `-t`. Now, either use `tmux kill-server` to kill all sessions, or use `tmux kill-session -t cpp-<session_id>` for every unwanted session. Session with id `0` does not need a `-0` suffix.

**Long answer**: `-t` is meant to create groups. When you used `-t` instead of `-s` and you already had an existing session named `cpp`, you created a new group named `cpp` and added another session named `cpp` with id `1`. Another run - another session added, id increments every time.